# Translating Python text game code into Pseudocode

Tags: python-3.x, pseudocode

As I am quite new to this,I am being asked to translate this code below into pseudocode and I would greatly appreciate if someone help me with this.

```
   # declaration
    rooms = {
        'Great Hall': {'South': 'Bedroom'},
        'Bedroom': {'North': 'Great Hall', 'East': 'Cellar'},
        'Cellar': {'West': 'Bedroom'}
    }
    state = 'Great Hall'
    # function
    def get_new_state(state, direction):
        new_state = state  # declaraing
        for i in rooms:  # loop
            if i == state:  # if
                if direction in rooms[i]:  # if
                    new_state = rooms[i][direction]  # assigning new_state
    
        return new_state  # return
    
    while (1):  # gameplay loop
        print('You are in ', state)  # printing state
        direction = input('Enter Which direction you want to go or enter exit: ')  # asking user
        direction = direction.capitalize()  # making first character capital remaining lower
        if (direction == 'Exit'):  # if
            exit(0)  # exit function
        if (direction == 'East' or direction == 'West' or direction == 'North' or direction == 'South'):  # if
            new_state = get_new_state(state, direction)  # calling function
            if new_state == state:  # if
                print('The room has wall in that direction enter other direction!')  # print
            else:
                state = new_state  # changing state value to new_state
        else:
            print('Invalid direction!!')  # print
```